# Issue with HDRI usage

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, hdri

I was trying different hdri for the scene to render this corvette in.To make the car appear on the surface of the hdri i took a plane and added the same environment texture to it.After that i turned the scale of the plane on Z axis of the plane to -1.Now after getting the same settings for object as the world,the plane reflections are a bit different from the world hdri.You can see it rendered view.It is clearly visible.So changed i the output from surface to volume.THe tricked worked and the reflection became same as the background hdri.However now i am not able to cast shadow on the plane by using sun lamp as i was able to do in surface output.Can you help me sort this out?I want the plane same as background hdri so that the plane blends in with the environment and I also want the reflections at the same time. I am working on eevee. The node editor on right is for the plane object and the editor in the middle is for the world settings

[image]

Comment: shadow catcher option is available on cycles only.I was creating shadow from a sun lamp